# How to fit a user defined custom gaussian function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a custom function - a1*exp(-2*((x-b1)/c1)^2) and x,y data to get the values of a, b and c. I am trying to fit the x,y data to this function. I have tried using the gauss1 function in matlab, but, my function is slightly different(the standard gauss1 function is a1*exp(-*((x-b1)/c1)^2)) without the multiplier 2. Can someone help me into how can I get a fit for this function in Matlab.

Thanks

Ankit

Answer (score 2):

Get a,b,c with gauss1, and use `c1 = c*sqrt(2)` and `b1=b` and `a1=-a`.

Comment: Well you can get the answer just with using gauss1 and modifying slightly the output.

Comment: @seb: please reformulate the answer as an answer, not a question, i.e fit like this, modify like that

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you have the [Curve Fitting Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/curvefitting/) is to use [`cftool`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/curvefit/cftool.html), which has a custom equation option.